# Select nodes with a certain child hierarchy

Tags: jquery

I want to write a jQuery selector which matches a set of div nodes (the bold line below):

- **all `div` nodes where class = `.link`**

  - who contains a `div` node where class = `.entry`

    - who contains a `p` node where class = `.title`

      - who contains an `a` node where href starts with `http://i.imgur.com/`

(Click image below for full size. To test stuff out, visit http://reddit.com and use Firebug (jQuery is loaded)):
[image: Firebug screenshot containing part of Reddits DOM]

Comment: Could you please post your HTML (not a picture of it)?

Comment: Did you mean all div nodes where class = `.link` *who contain* div nodes where class = `.entry`? Or did you mean all div nodes where class = `.link` *and* all div nodes where class = `.entry`?

Comment: `$('p.title a[href^="http://i.imgur.com/"]', 'div.title div.entry')`

Comment: @adeneo That selects the anchor though.

Comment: @Kent Well in that case you can use `$('div.link:has(div.entry:has(p.title:has(a[href^="http://i.imgur.com/"])))')`

Comment: @Asad: Well, as stated the bold line is what I want to match. So _who contains_, not _and_. I'll update to make it clearer. Regarding the HTML, I thought this was easy for someone with jQuery knowledge. I'm just starting out using it. To find the HTML simply visit http://reddit.com (I'm trying to create a Greasemonkey script for it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('div.link').has('div.entry:has(p.title:has(a[href^="http://i.imgur.com/"]))');
```

EDIT: It is actually `:has` not `:contains` (just saw undefined's answer)

Comment: I don't get any match when running this in Firebug on http://reddit.com. Even though I see many imgur.com links. Any ideas?

Comment: @Kent For some reason `.link` does not match correctly. I have updated my answer.

Comment: When I tried myself I also caught that problem. Strange. Anyway, it works now! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `has` method and attribute `starts with` selector.

```
$('div.link div.entry').has('p.title:has(a[href^="http://i.imgur.com/"])');
```

<sub>Edit:</sub>

Or `filter` method:

```
var $entries = $('div.link').filter(function() {
    return $('p.title:has(a[href^="http://i.imgur.com/"])', this).length
})
```

Comment: It's a fine example. But it matches `div.entry`s and I want the `div.link`s. I apologize for my poorly formulated question!

Comment: @Kent Well you can just remove the `div.entry` from the selector. I have updated the `filter` method.

Comment: If I do, it doesn't care about the `class = .entry` criteria. Altough it might not matter for this specific case, I prefer to have it so it doesn't start matching too much in the future.

Comment: @Kent Try this `var $links = $('div.link').filter(function() {
    return $('.entries p.title:has(a[href^="http://i.imgur.com/"])', this).length
})`